# Javascript does not work when signed in or when comments are open

Tags: 8, javascript

This is my info.yml file.

```
name: tnt
description: Drupal 8 starter theme
type: theme
core: 8.x

libraries:
  - tnt/global-styling

regions:
  header: 'Header'
  primary_menu: 'Primary menu'
  breadcrumb: 'Breadcrumb'
  content: 'Content'
  sidebar_first: 'Sidebar first'
  footer_first: 'Footer first'
```

This is my libraries.yml file.

```
global-styling:
  version: VERSION
  css:
    theme:
      styles/style1.css: {}
  js:
    js/js1.js: {}
  dependencies:
   - core/jquery
```

This is my JavaScript file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  alert("Here I am");   

});// end ready
```

This works fine unless one of these conditions is true.

- User is signed in
- User is on a page where comments are open

Obviously, I had much more complicated JavaScript code, but I reduced it to something simpler to illustrate the point.

I am currently using Drupal 8.1.10.

How do I get this to work when users are signed in and/or comments are open?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Notice that you stated facts without asking any explicit question. Stack Exchange doesn't work well with implicit questions. What did you try? What did you obtain with what you tried? What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: HI, Added specific questons

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? Are there errors in watchlog?

Answer (score 0):

To get the jquery alias `$` working in drupal, you have map it like this:

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    alert("Here I am");   
  });
})(jQuery);
```

The document ready function is not the best option, better use `Drupal.behaviors` and `once()`:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview

Comment: That didn't work but I remembered something from Drupal 7. Had to use "jQuery" instead of "$" so new javascript reads as follows:                             [code]jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    alert("Here I am");
});[/code]

Comment: That's the same, whether you define the alias $ or replace any $ in your code with jQuery.